# Help?!? This has a crack in it. And after I’ve been driving it I hear a cranking noise. What is this and did I damage my car badly?

Tags: toyota, leak, camry, cracking

[image]
I have a 1995 Toyota Camry. When I cut my car off from driving. It leaks and make a little noise. Today I lifted the hood. I should’ve been did that. And saw this crack with liquid bubbling. I’ve been driving it like this about 40 miles a day. It also leaks under the car.

Answer (score 2):

That is a crack in the upper tank on your cooling system Radiator, the radiator needs to be replaced soon or engine damage will result.

They do this when they get old, the tank is made of plastic and eventually will develop cracks.

Comment: How can I tell if the engine is severely damaged?

Comment: and is there a temporary fix until I can get to a mechanic?

Comment: I don't know of any temporary fix for that type of crack. Stop driving it until you can get a new radiator installed or risk damaging your engine due to overheating. Keep it full of antifreeze is all you can do until it makes it to your mechanic.

Comment: Okay thanks. What's the name of the part I should order?

Comment: Cooling system Radiator

Answer (score 0):

What you should do until you get this repaired is fill up the radiator with water whenever the engine is cool. You need to replace all the coolant/water that falls out. If you drive with an empty cooling system you won't have a good time. Good luck!